# Почему выходит -128?

Tags: java

Создадим переменную, увеличим на 1, выведем на печать:

```
byte a = 127; 
a++; 
System.out.print(a);
```

Почему выходит -128? Логично, что byte не может быть больше 127. Но хотелось бы точного ответа.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

В переменной типа `byte` содержится 8 бит. Старший (самый левый) бит отвечает за знак. Если старший бит `1`, то число отрицательное, если `0` - то неотрицательное (ноль или положительное).

127 в двоичном представлении - `01111111`.

Если к этому числу добавить 1, то получится `10000000` (`-128`), то есть увеличивая число, мы "залезли" в знаковый бит и превратили число в самое маленькое отрицательное, которое может содержать тип `byte`.

Answer (score 13):

Все дело в двоичном представлении числа.

Переменная типа `byte`, как ни странно, занимает ровно `1 байт`, а как [известно](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82) это `8 бит` (в подавляющем большинстве случаев).

Число `127` из *10-ой системы счисления* выглядит как `0111 1111` в *двоичной системе счисления*. Таким образом, при прибавлении `1`, число приобретает вид `1000 0000`, что при приведении в десятичную систему счисления без всяких преобразований (положительные же числа именно так и представлены в памяти, т.е. `прямым кодом`), получается число `128`, но отрицательные же числа в *java* (да и вообще на большинстве *ЭВМ*) представлены [дополнительным кодом числа](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0)) (необходимым для того, чтобы операции сложения и вычитания выполнялись одинаково для знаковых и беззнаковых чисел), в котором старший разряд (т.е. самый старший бит байта) является знаковым.

Таким образом, если старший бит байта переменной типа `byte` имеет значение `0`, то число, находящееся в этом байте, записано в прямом коде и является беззнаковым (положительным), иначе если `1`, то переменная определенно представляет отрицательное число, записанное в `дополнительном коде`.

Чтобы вам стало понятнее, то представьте, что затем происходит преобразование числа из обратного кода (т.е. пусть мы будем получать прямой код числа, взятого по модулю):

> Все разряды числа инвертируются, а к результату прибавляется 1

Это чтобы было понятно как представлены внутри байта остальные числа {`-127, -126, ..., -1`}, в нашем же случае после применения данной операции мы снова получим двоичное число `1000 0000` (в отличие от применения данной операции к другим отрицательным числам из данного множества), т.е. `128`, но мы знаем, что в доп коде у этого числа *старший разряд* был `1`, а значит - это знаковое (отрицательное) число `-128`.

Answer (score 6):

Потому что Java никак не обрабатывает переполнение и в результате применения математических операций на двоичных числах получается такой результат.